# IE11 - Can't add second optgroup to select

Tags: javascript

This JavaScript works as expected in Chrome and Firefox. But the client is using IE11, and in that browser, only the first optgroup gets added to the select:

```
case "MPNA – MP Advisory North American Dividend":

    document.getElementById("Mandate 2").style.display = "";
    document.getElementById("Objective").style.display = "";
    var og1 = document.createElement("optgroup");
    og1.setAttribute("label", "Single Manager Fixed Income Mandates:");
    select2.add(og1);
    select2.options[select2.options.length] = new Option('5LBP – 5 Year CDN Laddered Bond', '5LBP – 5 Year CDN Laddered Bond');
    select2.options[select2.options.length] = new Option('FBCI – Franklin Bissett (Canadian Fixed Income)', 'FBCI – Franklin Bissett (Canadian Fixed Income)');
    select2.options[select2.options.length] = new Option('FTUI – Franklin Templeton (US Fixed Income)', 'FTUI – Franklin Templeton (US Fixed Income)');
    select2.options[select2.options.length] = new Option('GCFI – Guardian Capital (Canadian Fixed Income)', 'GCFI – Guardian Capital (Canadian Fixed Income)');
    select2.options[select2.options.length] = new Option('USLB – 5 Year US Laddered Bond', 'USLB – 5 Year US Laddered Bond');

    var og2 = document.createElement("optgroup");
    og2.setAttribute("label", "Risk Control Optimized Portfolio:");
    select2.add(og2);
    select2.options[select2.options.length] = new Option('RC10 – Risk Control - Stability (Pools)', 'RC10 – Risk Control - Stability (Pools)');
    select2.options[select2.options.length] = new Option('RC11 – Risk Control - Stability (SEG &amp% Pools)', 'RC11 – Risk Control - Stability (SEG & Pools)');
    break;
```

In Chrome, the correct appearance:
[image]

In IE, only the first optgroup is added:
[image]

Anyone have an explanation or workaround? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options need to go inside the optgroup. It's a grouping element, not a dividing element.

```js
const select2 = document.createElement("select");
document.body.appendChild(select2);

const og1 = document.createElement("optgroup");
og1.setAttribute("label", "Single Manager Fixed Income Mandates:");
select2.appendChild(og1);
og1.appendChild(new Option('5LBP – 5 Year CDN Laddered Bond', '5LBP – 5 Year CDN Laddered Bond'));
og1.appendChild(new Option('FBCI – Franklin Bissett (Canadian Fixed Income)', 'FBCI – Franklin Bissett (Canadian Fixed Income)'));
og1.appendChild(new Option('FTUI – Franklin Templeton (US Fixed Income)', 'FTUI – Franklin Templeton (US Fixed Income)'));
og1.appendChild(new Option('GCFI – Guardian Capital (Canadian Fixed Income)', 'GCFI – Guardian Capital (Canadian Fixed Income)'));
og1.appendChild(new Option('USLB – 5 Year US Laddered Bond', 'USLB – 5 Year US Laddered Bond'));

const og2 = document.createElement("optgroup");
og2.setAttribute("label", "Risk Control Optimized Portfolio:");
select2.appendChild(og2);
og2.appendChild(new Option('RC10 – Risk Control - Stability (Pools)', 'RC10 – Risk Control - Stability (Pools)'));
og2.appendChild(new Option('RC11 – Risk Control - Stability (SEG &amp% Pools)', 'RC11 – Risk Control - Stability (SEG & Pools)'));
```